# Java Regular Expression to extract everything BUT what is between two brackets

Tags: java, regex

I am struggling and have looked up many resources. I appreciate your time and patience. I would like to extract everything in a string BUT what is between two brackets, including the brackets themselves.

Duck, Donald [CTO Enterprise]
Mouse, Micky [HR Employee Engagement]

I would like to just have:

Duck, Donald
Mouse, Micky

So far I have been badly manipulating

```
[A-Za-z, ][^\[(.*?)\]]
```

But to no avail.

Thank You!!

Comment: Split, `s.split("\\[[^\\]\\[]*\\]")`, or replace, `s.replaceAll("\\s*\\[[^\\]\\[]*\\]", "")`

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
\s*\[.*?[^\[]*\]
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`\s*`** -  matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`) zero or more times.
>
> **`[.*?[^\[]*\]`** - Matches the square brackets literally and matches everything inside square brackets lazily. It will even replace the nested brackets if that is your requirement too.

[image: pictorial representation]

You can find the demo of the regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/EzdPrD/3)

**Implementation in java:**

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Duck, Donald [CTO Enterprise] Mouse, Micky [HR Employee Engagement]";
        System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\s*\\[.*?[^\\[]*\\]", ""));
    }
}
// outputs: Duck, Donald Mouse, Micky
```

You can find the sample run of the above code in [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/HkL4AP2nU)